# winbatch windows scripting language object oriented?

Tags: oop, class, scripting, batch-file

I was wondering if winbatch have some object oriented characteristics. For example is it able to create to a class? I know it is not a object oriented scripting language.

Comment: I assumed he meant Windows Batch, or just Batch/MS DOS

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make pseudo OOP (I think one of the people I know did) if you kept at it, but I highly doubt it has any default methods of doing OOP. It's not made to do major applications with, so practically every project worth using OOP in should certainly not be coded in Batch.

Answer (score 0):

WinBatch was one of the very first scripting languages for MS Windows, introduced when Windows 3.0 was current. It has grown with the years and is now a significant language, with hundreds upon hundreds of functions, able to also run .NET and C# code. As an interpreted language it is slow, but there isn't much it cannot do and tons-and-tons that it can do much better/faster than any other similar language of which I am aware.

But No, WinBatch is not object-oriented. It is a procedural scripting language that can be compiled. Still, you would be best served to ask this question on the WinBatch message board. It is well attended and you would receive a definitive answer.

From winbatch.com, "Scripting tools are the "quick and dirty" procedural, interpreted languages used as glue for component integration. WinBatch is a macro scripting language specifically designed for Windows and Windows NT. It features a unique language called WIL for Windows Interface Language. It is specialized for controlling the Windows operating system, the PC it runs on, and the software applications used on that computer.
No other scripting tool offers so much control over the Windows environment"

I can vouch for this. I've written dozens of compiled apps with WB, up to 10,000+ lines of code plus a full-featured commercial app. I've also seen WB compiled apps in global distribs from the likes of HP, Intel, Honeywell, etc. Development is Rapid, learning curve is Fast. "Easy-to-use" is not misleading, and the WB forum (forum.winbatch.com) is superb.

However, it is commercial (shareware) and not inexpensive. (Disclaimer: I am just a long-time customer, never associated with any WB/Wilson company.)